# Scipy minimize with multiple linear constraints

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I'm having an issue trying to implement an NLP using `scipy`, given a dynamic vector `x` and a static utility vector `u`, where I'm interested in minimizing a utility function of the form:

```
utility_vector = np.array([0.10, 0.08, 0.05, 0.075, 0.32, 
                           0.21, 0.18, 0.05, 0.03, 0.12])
x0 = np.zeros((10, )) 
groups = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
z_group = [0.25, 0.55, 0.2]

def opt_func(x, u, target):
    utility = (x * u).sum()
    return (utility - target)**2
```

Alongside a number of sub-total linear constraints of the form `x[selection].sum() = Z1` and a total constraint of `x.sum() = 1.0`. However, when applying these constraints via `scipy.minimize`, my response vector does not seem to satisfy the sub-total linear constraints being specified.

```
cons = []

# total linear constraint 
cons.append({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: 1 - x.sum()})

# sub-total linear constraints
for idx, select in enumerate(groups):
    cons.append({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: z_group[idx] - x[select].sum()})

bnds = tuple((0, None) for i in range(10))
        
res = minimize(fun=opt_func, 
               x0=x0, 
               method='trust-constr', 
               bounds=bnds, 
               constraints=tuple(cons), 
               args=(utility_vector, 
                     0.16),
               tol=1e-4) 

print(res)

print(f'\nTotal allocation sum {res.x.sum()}')

# output
for idx, select in enumerate(groups):
    print(f'{select} fields difference {z_group[idx] - res.x[select].sum()}')
```

Any help or insight into how I may go about addressing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: rather than adding a constraint making sure that x[i1:i2] = Z1 and sum(x) = 1, why not just have x[i2] = Z1 - x[i1:i2-1] and have x[0] += 1 - sum(x) in your opt_func and pass in a smaller vector? It should simplify the code and let you use other methods as well

Comment: i've revised the question, with a more detailed example illustrating the constraint issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scipy Optimization Not Running when I try to set constraints using a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45491376/scipy-optimization-not-running-when-i-try-to-set-constraints-using-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

#### Late binding in loops

This problem is being caused by late binding. When you use a lambda inside of a loop, there is a somewhat counter-intuitive behavior: the variable is looked up at the time that the function is called, not the time that the function is defined.

Example:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
funcs = []
for n in numbers:
    funcs.append(lambda: n)
for func in funcs:
    print(func())
```

You might expect that this defines 3 functions that print out the value of `n` at the time that each function was defined. But actually, this prints out:

```
3
3
3
```

Consequentially, this means that only your last `z_group` constraint is being checked.

[More information about late binding.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452770/python-lambdas-binding-to-local-values)

#### Fix

Here are two ways you could fix this.

First, you could turn this lambda into a function.

```py
def single_constraint(idx, select):
    def inner(x):
        return z_group[idx] - x[select].sum()
    return inner


for idx, select in enumerate(groups):
    cons.append({'type': 'eq', 'fun': single_constraint(idx, select)})
```

Alternatively, you could include idx and select as default values of the function. This will cause them to bind when the function is defined.

```
for idx, select in enumerate(groups):
    cons.append({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x, idx=idx, select=select: z_group[idx] - x[select].sum()})
```

I personally prefer the first way, but you could make an argument either way.

#### Linearity

All of your constraints are linear. While SciPy supports the use of functions to provide arbitrary nonlinear constraints, if you can turn your constraint into a linear constraint, it will run much faster. With nonlinear constraints, SciPy only knows whether it is currently satisfying the constraint or not. With a linear constraint, SciPy can determine not only whether it is satisfying the constraint, but also what directions it can legally move along without violating the constraint. This is much faster than trial and error.

Here's an example of how to use LinearConstraint.

```
n_variables = len(x0)
sum_constraint = scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint(A=np.ones((1, n_variables)), lb=1, ub=1)
group_sum_matrix = np.zeros((len(groups), n_variables))
group_sum_target = np.array(z_group)
for idx, select in enumerate(groups):
    group_sum_matrix[idx, select] = 1
group_sum_constraint = scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint(A=group_sum_matrix, lb=group_sum_target, ub=group_sum_target)

bnds = tuple((0, None) for i in range(10))
        
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun=opt_func, 
               x0=x0, 
               method='trust-constr', 
               bounds=bnds, 
               constraints=[sum_constraint, group_sum_constraint], 
               args=(utility_vector, 
                     0.16),
               tol=1e-4)
```

This can find a better solution in 10 iterations than the nonlinear version can find in 1000 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

In a generic sense, and assuming that you actually need NLP, Nick ODell's answer is correct.

However, you don't need NLP. For your current inputs (and plausibly, many other kinds of input), an exact solution is possible, which means that the distinction between least-squares and absolute linear error is meaningless. For that reason, and because linear systems are generally faster and more predictable, you should linearize the entire problem:

```py
import scipy.sparse
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint
import numpy as np

'''
Minimize |x.u - target|
Variables:
    x: 10-vector, x >= 0
    err: scalar absolute error
'''

utility = np.array((
    0.10, 0.08, 0.05, 0.075, 0.32,
    0.21, 0.18, 0.05, 0.030, 0.12,
))
groups = ((0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9))
z_group = (0.25, 0.55, 0.2)
target = 0.16

sum_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=np.concatenate((
        np.ones_like(utility),
        (0,),
    )),
    lb=1, ub=1,
)

#  x.u - target <= err      -x.u + err >= -target
# -x.u + target <= err      +x.u + err >=  target
err_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=np.block([
        [-utility, 1],
        [ utility, 1],
    ]),
    lb=(-target, +target),
)

# group indices as a sparse matrix
group_idx = scipy.sparse.csr_array(
    (
        np.ones_like(utility),    # data
        [  # indices
            i
            for group in groups
            for i in group
        ],
        np.cumsum([  # indptr
            0,
            *(len(g) for g in groups),
        ]),
    ),
    shape=(len(groups), 1 + utility.size),
)
group_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=group_idx,
    lb=z_group, ub=z_group,
)

result = milp(
    c=np.concatenate((
        np.zeros_like(utility),  # utility not optimized
        (1,),                    # abs error minimized
    )),
    bounds=Bounds(lb=0),  # all variables non-negative
    integrality=0,        # all variables continuous
    constraints=(
        sum_constraint,
        err_constraint,
        group_constraint,
    ),
)
if not result.success:
    raise ValueError(result.message)
print(result.message)
x, (abs_err,) = np.split(result.x, (utility.size,))
print(f'target= {target}, actual={x.dot(utility):.4f}, |error|={abs_err}')
print('x =')
print(x)
print('Target sums =', z_group)
print('       Sums =', group_constraint.A @ result.x)
```

```
Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
target= 0.16, actual=0.1600, |error|=0.0
x =
[0.         0.         0.25       0.         0.23636364 0.31363636
 0.         0.         0.2        0.        ]
Target sums = (0.25, 0.55, 0.2)
       Sums = [0.25 0.55 0.2 ]
```

In fact, the problem is so under-constrained that you could easily force all but one of the groups to take uniform values:

```
target= 0.16, actual=0.1600, |error|=0.0
x =
[0.0625     0.0625     0.0625     0.0625     0.05852273 0.49147727
 0.05       0.05       0.05       0.05      ]
Target sums = (0.25, 0.55, 0.2)
       Sums = [0.25 0.55 0.2 ]
```

or even

```
target= 0.16, actual=0.1600, |error|=0.0
x =
[0.25 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.55 0.09 0.   0.11 0.  ]
Target sums = (0.25, 0.55, 0.2)
       Sums = [0.25 0.55 0.2 ]
```

This all suggests that you should move the error-objective to a zero-error constraint, and introduce a different objective that further refines the problem based on domain knowledge. With no objective set, this looks like

```py
import scipy.sparse
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint
import numpy as np

# Variables: x, 10-vector, x >= 0

utility = np.array((
    0.10, 0.08, 0.05, 0.075, 0.32,
    0.21, 0.18, 0.05, 0.030, 0.12,
))
groups = ((0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9))
z_group = (0.25, 0.55, 0.2)
target = 0.16

# group indices as a sparse matrix
group_idx = scipy.sparse.csr_array(
    (
        np.ones_like(utility),  # data
        [  # indices
            i
            for group in groups
            for i in group
        ],
        np.cumsum([  # indptr
            0,
            *(len(g) for g in groups),
        ]),
    ),
)
group_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=group_idx, lb=z_group, ub=z_group)
sum_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=np.ones_like(utility), lb=1, ub=1)
target_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=utility, lb=target, ub=target)

result = milp(
    c=np.zeros_like(utility),  # no objective
    bounds=Bounds(lb=0),       # all non-negative
    integrality=0,             # all continuous
    constraints=(sum_constraint, target_constraint, group_constraint),
)
if not result.success:
    raise ValueError(result.message)

print(result.message)
print(f'sum~1 = {result.x.sum()}')
print(f'utility~{target} = {result.x.dot(utility):.4f}')
print(f'groups~{z_group} = {group_idx @ result.x}')
print('x =')
print(result.x)
```

```
Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
sum~1 = 1.0
utility~0.16 = 0.1600
groups~(0.25, 0.55, 0.2) = [0.25 0.55 0.2 ]
x =
[0.         0.         0.25       0.         0.23636364 0.31363636
 0.         0.         0.2        0.        ]
```