# Forcing an 'eq' constraint function to 0 in scipy.optimize.minimize causes a failure

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I want to put a "dummy" constraint into my scipy.optimize.minimize call so that I can use it to interrogate variables as they change.  I add this simple constraint:

```
# Code that fails.
def tracer(actuals, sReturn): # To allow troubleshooting and insight.
    print('You asked to return {}.'.format(sReturn))
    return sReturn

consTracer = { 'type': 'eq', 'fun': tracer, 'args': (0,) } # Fails!
```

The code goes on to call minimize() with `method = 'SLSQP'`.  But it gets this message:

```
Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem    (Exit mode 6)
            Current function value: -0.0
            Iterations: 1
            Function evaluations: 8
            Gradient evaluations: 1
Failed to find solution. Exit code 6
```

Now, I can solve this by changing it to 'ineq' and returning 1.0.  So this works:

```
# Code that works.
def tracer(actuals, sReturn): # To allow troubleshooting and insight.
    print('You asked to return {}.'.format(sReturn))
    return sReturn

consTracer = { 'type': 'ineq', 'fun': tracer, 'args': (1,) } # Works!
```

That's a fine work-around, and I understand why it works, but **I would like a conceptual understanding of why 'eq' of a hard coded 0.0 fails**.

Wouldn't it be the case that every time it called "tracer" and saw 0.0, it would essentially find the constraint passed, and move on to the other constraints.

Note there are eight other constraints, and without the "tracer" constraint above, it all works fine.

**Why wouldn't an 'eq' constraint that always returns 0.0 just work?**

The full working code is below.  (Update, there are two bodies of working code, and the second narrows it even more)

Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
from   scipy.optimize import minimize

chips   = 5 # You have five chips to play.
value   = [3,8,7,2,5,4,1] # Each position has a different value.
bounds = list((0,2) for _ in range(len(value))) # Max 2 chips per position.
actuals = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

print("@ value = {}".format(value))
print("@ actuals = {}".format(actuals))
print("@ bounds = {}".format(bounds))

def objective(actuals):
    return -np.sum(actuals * value) # Maximize the chips * position.

def useAll(actuals):
    return np.sum(actuals) - chips # Use all your chips.

consUseAll = { 'type': 'eq', 'fun': useAll }

def tracer(actuals, sReturn): # To allow troubleshooting and insight.
    print('You asked to return {}.'.format(sReturn))
    return sReturn

# Pick one of the following: <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
consTracer = { 'type': 'eq', 'fun': tracer, 'args': (0,) } # Fails!
# consTracer = { 'type': 'ineq', 'fun': tracer, 'args': (1,) } # Works!

constraints = [consUseAll, consTracer]

solution = minimize (
                fun = objective,
                 x0 = actuals,
             bounds = bounds,
             method = 'SLSQP',
        constraints = constraints,
            options = {'disp':True}
)

if (solution.success) and (solution.status == 0): # Solution is feasible and optimal.
    print("@ solution.fun (inverted) = {} # Expecting 35.".format(-round(solution.fun)))
    print(solution.x.round())
elif solution.status != 0:
    print("Failed to find solution. Exit code", solution.status)
else:
    print(solution.message) # Something else went wrong.
```

UPDATE: Forget my dummy tracer function.  Notice that even if I do a "round" on the return value of the constraint function it fails.  If you run it without the "round", it gets into tiny fractions.  But I wonder if it needs those tiny fractions somehow?

Try the code below with and without the commented line that does the rounding and see what happens.

```
import numpy as np
from   scipy.optimize import minimize

chips   = 5 # You have five chips to play.
value   = [3,8,7,2,5,4,1] # Each position has a different value.
bounds = list((0,2) for _ in range(len(value))) # Max 2 chips per position.
actuals = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

def objective(actuals):
    return -np.sum(actuals * value) # Maximize the chips times position.

def useAll(actuals):
    fReturn = np.sum(actuals) - chips
#   fReturn = round(fReturn) # <<<<< Note that if we round, it fails too.
    return fReturn

constraints = { 'type': 'eq', 'fun': useAll }

solution = minimize (
                fun = objective,
                 x0 = actuals,
             bounds = bounds,
             method = 'SLSQP',
        constraints = constraints,
            options = {'disp':True}
)

if (solution.success) and (solution.status == 0): # Solution is feasible and optimal.
    print("@ solution.fun (inverted) = {} # Expecting 35.".format(-round(solution.fun)))
    print(solution.x.round())
elif solution.status != 0:
    print("Failed to find solution. Exit code", solution.status)
else:
    print(solution.message) # Something else went wrong.
```

I further suspect that the constraint functions for 'eq' must allow for movement "past" the zero line.  Consider this output, made by putting a print in the "useAll" function:

```
-4.999999985098839
-4.999999985098839
-4.999999985098839
5.329070518200751e-15
5.329070518200751e-15
1.4901166522918174e-08
1.4901166522918174e-08
1.4901166522918174e-08
```

Notice that it starts out less than zero, then crosses over into more than zero.  Which I suspect means it's ensuring it's "looks past" zero for some reason, then comes back and says, "meh, that's zero alright".  That's obviously an intuitive observation not a rigorous one!  But there's some thing like that going in.

Comment: Why do either of these? Why not just print from the objective?

Comment: This can be caused by having two constraints which are exactly equal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45491376/scipy-optimization-not-running-when-i-try-to-set-constraints-using-a-for-loop I'm not sure if this is the problem. Can you provide a complete runnable example?

Comment: @Reinderien, I want to keep it modular.  By breaking it out, it's easily turned off.  And I don't want to clutter the logic of actual constraint functions.

Comment: @NickODell, full working code added.  Happy to do it.  Was able to reproduce it with the toy problem above.  Thanks!

Comment: @NickODell, thanks for the link to the other issue.  I've seen that root cause produce this same error, but I don't think it's what's happening here.

Comment: This is also discussed here, but never answered: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247534/scipy-optimization-singular-matrix-c-in-lsq-subproblem

Comment: See also this issue on the SciPy bug tracker: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7314 I'm not sure I understand the rationale about constraint qualification, but maybe it will help you.