# List of scipy hermite polynomials behave unexpectedly when used as lambda functions

Tags: python, scipy, hermite

I want to build a container of [Hermite polynomials](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.hermite.html) (link to scipy's hermite doc) of different orders. From what the doc says, I expect `scipy.special.hermite` to accept the order `n` and return a function - an Hermite polynomial of order `n`.

This seems to work fine with single functions. But when I try to use a list of Hermitte polynomials by realising them as lambda functions, it seems they will all be reset to the last polynomial:

```
from scipy.special import hermite
base_funcs = [lambda x: hermite(i)(x) for i in range(5)]

[f(1) for f in base_funcs]
Out[40]: [-20.0, -20.0, -20.0, -20.0, -20.0]
hermite(0)(1)
Out[41]: 1.0
hermite(4)(1)
Out[42]: -20.0
```

Is there a way to initiate a container of different Hermite polynomials properly, without previous elements being overwritten by subsequent ones in the container apprehension statement? Thanks!

Comment: That's the [late binding closure *gotcha*](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures).  See the link for suggestions on how to fix it, or search for that term here on stackoverflow (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791680/scipy-optimize-minimize-slsqp-with-linear-constraints-fails/37792650#37792650).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks the suggestions made in your answer work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Warren's comment says, this is due to Python's late binding mechanism. To circumvent it, one solution is to include the loop variable as one of the function's default arguments. i.e.

```
[lambda x, i=i: hermite(i)(x) for i in range(5)]
```

Suggested reading: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures.