# Passing string into a lambda function

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, scipy

I am trying to automatically generate lambda functions given a list of lists of strings to generate constraints for a `scipy.optimize.minimize()` routine.  I have a `list` of string pairs, which I need to pass into each lambda function constraint, as so:

```py
list = [
["parameter1", "parameter2"],
["parameter3", "parameter4"]
]

constraints = []
for pair in list:
    constraints.append( {"type":"ineq","fun": lambda p: p[param_names.index(pair[0])]-p[param_names.index(pair[1])]} )
```

However, when this list of constraints is passed to `scipy.optimize.minimize()`, the constraints are ignored.  Alternatively, when I explicitly define the strings like so

```py
cons = [
{'type':'ineq','fun': lambda p: p[param_names.index("parameter1")]-p[param_names.index("parameter2")] },
{'type':'ineq','fun': lambda p: p[param_names.index("parameter3")]-p[param_names.index("parameter4")] }
]
```

`scipy.optimize.minimize()` obeys the constraints.  I believe this is a problem with how I'm defining the lambda function, namely trying to pass variables (the strings) into the lambda function, and not a problem with `scipy.optimize.minimize()`.  I need my code to be able to parse a list of pairs of strings as above to automatically define these lambda functions and constraints, since the list can vary depending on the situation.

Is there a way to pass variables from outside the lambda function into the lambda function? Or another way I should be doing this?

Comment: Just to be sure, some strings in the list miss an 'e' (cmp.: `paramter1` and `parameter1`). Typo or not?

Comment: Yes that is a typo, sorry.

Comment: So without the typo the code works as expected?

Comment: The typo does not change the question or problem.  It was a mistake on my part when typing the question here.

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I can't reproduce the described behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791680/scipy-optimize-minimize-slsqp-with-linear-constraints-fails/37792650#37792650) to a similar question.  In your case, the problem is the use of the name `pair` in the lambda expression.  Because of Python's [late-binding closures](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures), `pair` will refer to the value that it has at the time the lambda is evaluated, not the value that it had when the lambda was defined. In your code, that probably means `pair` will always refer to the *last* element in `list`.

A possible [fix](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#id4):

```
constraints = []
for pair in list:
    constraints.append({"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda p, pair=pair: p[param_names.index(pair[0])]-p[param_names.index(pair[1])]})
```