# Why do constraints fail in scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

```
    def get_cons(self, ub, lb):
        cons = []
        for i in range(len(ub)):
            cons.append({'type':'ineq','fun':lambda x0:ub[i]-x0[i]})
            cons.append({'type':'ineq','fun':lambda x0:x0[i]-lb[i]})
        return cons
    ub = [1,3,1,1]
    lb = [0,0,0,0]
    cons = self.get_cons(self.ub, self.lb)
    res = minimize(fun, x0[:,i], method='SLSQP', constraints=cons)
```

Here fun is custom loss function
initial parameter is [0.08024884 0.14003958 0.0786131  0.00157402]. I expect all parameter>0,but after optimize parmeter is [-0.45684621  0.02531972 -0.10755587  0.2108312].

Whether this constraint fails?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791680/scipy-optimize-minimize-slsqp-with-linear-constraints-fails/37792650#37792650

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use generic constraints for adding simple bounds on the variables. Instead, pass the variable bounds via minimize's bound argument:

```py
bounds = [(l, u) for (l, u) in zip(lb, ub)]

res = minimize(fun, x0[:, i], bounds=bounds, method="SLSQP")
```

However, if you **really** want to pass the bounds as generic constraints, you need to capture the value of the loop variable `i`:

```py
for i in range(len(ub)):
    cons.append({'type':'ineq','fun': lambda x0, i=i: ub[i]-x0[i]})
    cons.append({'type':'ineq','fun': lambda x0: i=i: x0[i]-lb[i]})
return cons
```

Otherwise, each constraint shares the value of `i` of the last loop iteration, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result) for further details.